# How to get iwconfig to display signal level as dbm instead of a fraction

Tags: linux, iwconfig

When I run:

```
iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i quality
```

on my Raspberry Pi, with a wifi card installed, it reports back to me with:

```
Link Quality=99/100 Signal level=48/100 Noise level=0/100
```

How can I get iwconfig or some other network tool to report the signal level back to me in dBm instead of an arbitrary fraction?

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of the Network Interface Card or of the relatives Drivers.
To workaround you can use this simple formula I to do the conversion.

```
dbm=(fraction_of_total/2)-100
```

Of course is an approximation and results may vary from chipset to chipset but is how I solved.

You can alternatively find the correct Drivers if you know the wifi card is capable RSSI sampling. But that's usually not easy.